# Как получить доступ к объектному хранилищу Minio на хосте компьютера из контейнера docker?

Tags: c#, docker, amazon-s3, minio

## Проблема

У меня есть проект с микросервисной архитектурой и в нем я использую S3-совместимое хранилище Minio. Я столкнулся с проблемой, что при обращении к объектному хранилищу AWSClient отправляет запрос по адресу `http://<bucket-name>.minio`. Мои контейнеры находятся в сети типа bridge, поэтому сервис, отправляющий запрос, должен сопоставить хост имени контейнера с его адресом, но не может это сделать из-за префикс `<bucket-name>`.

## Что я пытался сделать

### Принудительный путь в url

Сначала я нашел свойство `ForcePathStyle` в классе `AmazonS3Config`, которое отвечает за принудительную path-style адресацию. Но проблема в том, что я внедряю `IAmazonS3` через DI и могу передать в метод привязки только `AWSOptions`, с вложенным в него `ClientConfig`, который не имеет данного свойства.

### Запуск хранилища на локальном хосте

Далее я запустил хранилище Minio в отдельной сети и сопоставил его порты с хостом моей машины.
В файле docker-compose добавил хосты для возможности доступа к "localhost моего компьютера":

```
    extra_hosts:
      - "<bucket-name>.host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

От части это сработало, теперь я могу получить доступ к хранилищу, но появилась другая проблема. Мой код выбрасывает исключение: `Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception: The specified bucket is not valid.`. При этом, если я обращаюсь к этому же bucket`у из сервиса, который запущен прямо на моей локальной машине, то все работает отлично.

Мне кажется, что проблема где-то в сопоставлении хостов. Скорее всего префикс `<bucket-name>` просто теряется. Но я не могу понять как это отладить и отследить. Возможно, есть какой-то более удобный способ для того чтобы связать мой сервис и объектную БД.

## Мой код

### Мой docker-compose:

```
 ...

  minio:
    image: minio/minio
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9001:9001"
    volumes:
      - minio_storage:/data
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: storage-api
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: 12345678
    command: server --console-address ":9001" /data
    container_name: minio    

 ...

  storageservice:
    container_name: shked-storage-service
    image: wayne301/shked-storageservice:dev
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "130:130"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Docker
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:130/
    networks:
      - shked-dev
    extra_hosts:
      - "shked-tasks.host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"

 ...
```

### Конфигурация моего сервиса

```
{
  "AWS": {
   "AccessKey": "tasks-service",
    "SecretKey": "12345678",
    "ServiceUrl": "http://host.docker.internal:9000",
    "BucketName": "shked-tasks"
  }
}
```

### UPD:

Проблему с исключением я пофиксил. Оказывается minio по-умолчанию поддерживает только path-style адресацию. Чтобы использовать virtual host адресацию нужно добавить следующую переменную среды:

```
MINIO_DOMAIN=mydomain.com
```

Вопрос как мне получить доступ к хранилищу внутри сети docker, чтобы не городить костыли с docker.internal.host, остается открытым.